# document.createElement sequence from html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form, let say somthing like

```html
<form id='form1'>
  <input type='text' name='name' class='Class2'>
  <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
</form>
```

that i create dynamicaly with javascript:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#create').on('click', function() {
    var form=document.createElement('form');
    form.id='form1';

    var txt=document.createElement('input');
    txt.type='text';
    txt.name='name';
    txt.classList.add('Class2');
    form.appendChild(txt);
        
    var btn=document.createElement('input');
    btn.type='submit';
    btn.value='SUBMIT';
    form.appendChild(btn);
    
    document.body.appendChild(form);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='create'>Create</button>
```

so... my question is there's a tool or something that create the "document.createElement"s sequence code from the html structure? Becouse i use bootstrap and want to create dynamically some modals, forms, tables, etc.; that already have in html, and if can minimize a little that work.

**PD**: i **DONT** want to use innerHTML and pass the form like a string "`<form id='form1'><input type='text' name='name' class='Class2'><input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'></form>`"

**EDIT**: one of the forms to "convert" will be

```html
<head>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  input[type=time],
  input[type=date],
  input[type=text],
  select {
    height: 28px;
    --margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  .float-input {
    position: relative;
    --width: 100%;
    --margin: 40px 0 20px;
  }
  
  .float-input input,
  .float-input select,
  .float-input textarea {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 14px 10px 0px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  }
  
  .float-input input,
  .float-input select {
    height: 41px;
  }
  
  .float-input input:focus,
  .float-input select:focus,
  .float-input textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  }
  
  .float-input label {
    color: #bbb;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  }
  
  .float-input input:focus~label,
  .float-input select:focus~label,
  .float-input textarea:focus~label,
  .float-input input:not(:placeholder-shown)~label,
  .float-input select:not(:placeholder-shown)~label,
  .float-input textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)~label {
    top: -2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    --color: #000;
  }
  .nav {
    background-color: lightblue !important;
    color:black;
}
.nav .nav-link {
    background-color: SkyBlue !important;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.nav .nav-link.active {
    background-color: #eff5ff !important;
    border-color:transparent !important;
}
.nav .nav-link:not(.active):hover{
    background-color: LightCyan !important;
}
.tab-content {
    background-color: #eff5ff;
}
.turnlist:hover,
.presuplist:hover{
    background:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4));;
}
</style>
<div class="patientData">
  <div class="mainP" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 30px; width: 470px; background-color: lightblue; border-radius: 10px; padding: 54px 10px 10px; z-index: 1;">
    <div class="Header ui-draggable-handle" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 470px; background-color: rgb(33, 150, 243); padding: 10px 0px; border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px; cursor: move; text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: 700; z-index: 2;">DATOS PACIENTE</div>
    <div class="closeP" style="position: absolute; left: 450px; top: -10px; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: red; border-radius: 50%; cursor: pointer; z-index: 3;"></div>
    <form id="formDataP" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="none">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-9">
          <select class="js-data-ajax w-100 select2-hidden-accessible" name="id" data-select2-id="select2-data-1-aip8" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-2-k6z6" style="width: 331.5px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-id-u1-container" aria-controls="select2-id-u1-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-id-u1-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="Buscar..."><span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Buscar...</span></span>
          <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span>
          </span>
          </span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-end"><button id="clearP" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" type="button">Limpiar</button></div>
      </div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
      <nav>
        <div class="row g-0">
          <div class="col nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="nav-tab" role="tablist"><button class="nav-link active" id="nav-tab-datos" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-datos" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-datos" aria-selected="true">Datos</button><button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab-contacto" data-bs-toggle="tab"
              data-bs-target="#nav-contacto" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contacto" aria-selected="false">Contacto</button><button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab-citas" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-citas" type="button" role="tab"
              aria-controls="nav-citas" aria-selected="false">Citas</button><button class="nav-link" id="nav-tab-presup" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-presup" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-presup" aria-selected="false">Presupuestos</button></div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="tab-content p-2" id="nav-tabContent" style="border-radius:0 0 10px 10px;">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-datos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab-datos">
          <div class="row g-1">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <div class="image"><label for="newimg2"><img id="blah" src="./Images/profiles/_profile.jpg" style="width:139px; height:139px;object-fit:cover;border-radius: 12px;border: 1px solid black"></label><input id="newimg2" name="FImg" type="file" accept="image/*"
                  onchange="document.getElementById(&quot;blah&quot;).src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])" hidden=""></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
                <div class="col float-input"><input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" required=""><label>Apellido/s</label></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
                <div class="col float-input"><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off" required=""><label>Nombre/s</label></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
                <div class="col-5 float-input">
                  <select name="sexo" placeholder=" " required="">
                    <option value="" selected="" hidden=""></option>
                    <option value="1">Masculino</option>
                    <option value="2">Femenino</option>
                    <option value="3">Otro</option>
                  </select><label>Sexo</label></div>
                <div class="col-7 float-input"><input type="date" name="birth" placeholder=" " required=""><label>Nacimiento</label></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="col-7 float-input"><input type="text" name="CURP" placeholder=" "><label>CURP</label></div>
            <div class="col-5 float-input"><input type="text" name="RFC" placeholder=" "><label>RFC</label></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="float-input" style=""><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder=" "><label>E-Mail</label></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contacto" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab-contacto">
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="float-input" style=""><input type="text" name="dir" placeholder=" "><label>Direccion</label></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="col-2">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="enum" placeholder=" " style=""><label>N° ext</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="inum" placeholder=" " style=""><label>N° int</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="ref" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Referencia</label></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="pais" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Pais</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="estado" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Estado</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="ciudad" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Ciudad</label></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="col-4">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="tel1" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Telefono 1</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="nota1" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Nota 1</label></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row g-1 mb-2">
            <div class="col-4">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="tel2" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Telefono 2</label></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
              <div class="float-input"><input type="text" name="nota2" placeholder=" " style=""><label>Nota 2</label></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-citas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab-citas">
          <div class="row mb-1 mx-0 border-bottom border-3" style="">
            <div class="col-3">Fecha</div>
            <div class="col-2">Hora</div>
            <div class="col">Medico</div>
          </div>
          <div id="lista-citas" style="height:214px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-presup" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-tab-presup">
          <div class="row mb-1 mx-0 border-bottom border-3" style="">
            <div class="col-2">N°</div>
            <div class="col-3">Fecha</div>
            <div class="col-2">Monto</div>
            <div class="col-auto">Encabezado: </div>
            <div class="col">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="lista-presup" style="height:214px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row g-1">
          <div class="col"></div>
          <div class="col text-center"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Guardar"></div>
          <div class="col text-center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block closeP">Cancelar</button></div>
          <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="bg" style="position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.4; z-index: 0;"></div>
</div>
```

I know i can rewrite all, but ther r like 14-15 forms larger than this one, and client DONT want to have them hidden on page, nor have it on a file and use `$.load("/path/to/html.html")` like sugested below.
Just asking if theres a easier way to "convert" this static html and "dynamically create" this form from an external js file with a function. And dont want to use innerHTML because some properties changes depending on other things, so plain text is not usefull.

Comment: If you have jQuery why aren't you using it?

Comment: If you've already created them as an HTML file, you could use `$.load("/path/to/html.html")`

Comment: Also, if the HTML exists, you can just clone the node to get a "safe" copy of it

Comment: @David client dont want this way.

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery to the full:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#create').on('click', function() {
    $('<form>', { id: 'form1' }).append(
      $('<input>', { type: 'text', name: 'name', "class": 'Class2' }),
      $('<input>', { type: 'submit', value: 'SUBMIT' })
    ).appendTo('body');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="create">Create</button>
```

Alternatively, you could already include this HTML in the static part of your page, but hidden, and then just call `$("#formA").show()` when you need it:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#create').on('click', function() {
    $('#form1').show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="create">Create</button>
<form id='form1' style='display:none'>
  <input type='text' name='name' class='Class2'>
  <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
</form>
```

When you need to allow more than one such form, then call jQuery's `.clone()` on it, and append the result to the document. But then you cannot use the `id` attribute, as HTML does not allow duplicate id values, and it is bad practice to then generate unique ids with something like a sequence number. Instead get the list of forms and select the one you need:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#create').on('click', function() {
    $('#form1').clone().removeAttr("id").appendTo('body').show();
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="create">Create</button>
<form id='form1' style='display:none'>
  <input type='text' name='name' class='Class2'>
  <input type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
</form>
```